# Regular Expressions

Tags: python, python-re

I'd like to extract the first occurrence of a certain text pattern from each page of a file but only the first occurrence. For example:

Consider the string below:

```
string = '''
Page 1:
112.ABC.123
112.ABC.123
112.XYZ.456
111.XYZ.456
'''
```

```
import re

result = re.compile(r'\d{3}[.]\w+[.]\d{3}')
matches = result.findall(string)
for match in matches:
print(match)
```

Output:

```
112.ABC.123
112.ABC.123
112.XYZ.456
111.XYZ.456
112.ABC.123
```

How can I output only the first occurrence of 112.ABC.123 and 111.XYZ.456? Can anyone help?

Comment: You want all unique matches or only the first match of the regular expression? If you want all unique matches, store the result in a set, then output the elements of that set. Or send the output to `sort | uniq`.

Comment: Thanks Calculuswhiz. I want just the first match of the regular expression. Would that require a different approach than the one you suggested?

Comment: How come you're using `findall` and a loop? The easiest way from your current code is just to put a `break` in your loop, but the best way to do this is to use `search`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 1):

use a `dict`

```py
import re

result = re.compile(r'\d{3}[.]\w+[.]\d{3}')
matches = result.findall(string)
matches_dict = dict.fromkeys(matches)
for key in matches_dict:
    print(key)
```

Output

```
112.ABC.123
112.XYZ.456
111.XYZ.456
```

Comment: Thanks, MrBrN197!